# How to invoke on the UI thread of a WinForm Component?

Tags: winforms, user-interface, components, invoke

I'm coding a WinForm component where I start a Task to do the actual processing and trap the exception on a continuation. From there I want to show the exception message on a UI element.

```
Task myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew (() => SomeMethod(someArgs));
myTask.ContinueWith (antecedant => uiTextBox.Text = antecedant.Exception.Message,
                     TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Now I get a cross-thread exception because the task is trying to update a UI element from a, obviously, non UI thread.

However, there is no Invoke or BeginInvoke defined in the Component class.

How to proceed from here?

---

**UPDATE**

Also, please note that Invoke/BeginInvoke/InvokeRequired are not available from my Component-derived class since Component doesn't provide them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just add a property to your component, allows the client to set a form reference that you can use to call its BeginInvoke() method.

That can be done automatically as well, preferable so nobody can forget.  It requires a bit of design time magic that's fairly impenetrable.  I didn't come up with this by myself, I got it from the ErrorProvider component.  Trusted source and all that.  Paste this into your component source code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
...
    [Browsable(false)]
    public Form ParentForm { get; set; }

    public override ISite Site {
        set {
            // Runs at design time, ensures designer initializes ParentForm
            base.Site = value;
            if (value != null) {
                IDesignerHost service = value.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost)) as IDesignerHost;
                if (service != null) this.ParentForm = service.RootComponent as Form;
            }
        }
    }
```

The designer automatically sets the ParentForm property when the user drops your component on a form.  Use ParentForm.BeginInvoke().

Comment: Pretty smart solution.

Comment: I observe this code is called at run-time, as well as doing what is expected when you drag-drop at design-time.

At run-time:  service.RootComponent as Form; returns null.

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegates to do this.

```
    delegate void UpdateStatusDelegate (string value);


    void UpdateStatus(string value)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            // We're not in the UI thread, so we need to call BeginInvoke
            BeginInvoke(new UpdateStatusDelegate(UpdateStatus), new object[]{value});
            return;
        }
        // Must be on the UI thread if we've got this far
        statusIndicator.Text = value;
    }
```

Comment: So, creating a delegate and invoking it will use the UI thread?

Comment: should do, not tested this code, but this is how I do in standard winforms

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work as the InvokeRequired method is not available inside a Component.

Comment: You typically do not need to create a delegate; use `Action<T>` instead.

Comment: Could you create an event on the component and then subscribe to it from further up?

Comment: `BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => UpdateStatus(value)))` should work, probably

Comment: @Sam BeginInvoke is not available under Component class and derived.

Comment: @Sam You're right. I've successfully used this solution before using the one from Hans which, in my opinion, is optimal since it may happen that I am not using a textbox but some other component later on.