# .NET (non-visual) component

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I need to create a non-visual component, `FooComponent`, that will do some management for all controls of type `Bar` that resides in its form.

I have the following constraints:

1. The `FooComponent` can only be added to forms.
2. Only one `FooComponent` per form is allowed.
3. `FooComponent` should register to the form closing event, and when it fires and to some function on all `Bar`'s and sent the `e.Cancel` value based on the returned values.

#1 and #2 above should be enforced on run-time as well as design time.
#3 event registration should be made automatically and not by the `FooComponent`'s users.

I searched Google and MSDN for some help and read about `Component` and `ComponentDesigner` classes, but I didn't find anything for the rescue.

What should I do?

Comment: I think you can look at the CodeDomSerializer ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.codedomserializer.aspx). It might be your best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) To control that the component can only be added to a form, use a `FooComponent` constructor that is passed a form, and don't define the default constructor.  It's called like:

```
FooComponent component = new FooComponent(this);
```

where the component is created from within the form itself.  By not-defining the default constructor, this:

```
FooComponent component = new FooComponent();
```

will not compile.

(2) Expose a `FooComponent` property on the form itself, and in the constructor of the `FooComponent`, set the passed form's `FooComponent` to `this`.

(3) Same thing, in the constructor for the `FooComponent`, register with the closing event for the form you passed

Put it all together and you get:

```
public class MyForm : Form {
    public FooComponent OwnedComponent { get; set; }
}


public class FooComponent {

    public FooComponent (MyForm OwnerForm) {
        OwnerForm.OwnedComponent = this;
        OwnerForm.FormClosing += MyCallback;
    }

    private void MyCallback(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        ...
    }

}
```

**EDIT**
Unfortunately, if you need the default constructor, and if it has to be a true drop-on-the-form Component, there's no way to enforce that a component is only created on a Form, or that the Form only has one instance of the component (not from within the component, anyway).

The problem is twofold:  
(1)  Dropping a component doesn't add the component to the form, it adds it to the form's `components` collection.  So even if you could get a handle to the parent/owner, it will never be a form.

(2)  As Neil pointed out, dropping a component onto a form calls the default constructor, which passes no parameters, and, of course, none of the component's properties (such as site or container) are populated.

Possibly helpful:  A component can be designed to be notified when it is created in a couple of ways:

(1)  By implementing a constructor that takes an `IContainer` parameter.  When the component is dropped on a form, the generated code will call this constructor, instead.  However, it will only do this at runtime, not design time.  But the container will be a handle to the form's `components` collection.

```
public FooComponent(IContainer container) {...}
```

(2)  By implementing `ISupportInitialize`.  When the component is dropped on a form, the generated code will additionally call `BeginInit()` and `EndInit()`.  In `EndInit()`, you can access properties such as the `Site` and `Container`.  Again, you'll only get this at runtime, not designtime, and throwing an exception here won't stop the component from being created.

Old, but excellent articles on Components and Controls from [MSDN Magazine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee310108.aspx) by Michael Weinhardt and Chris Sells.
[April 2003 Building Windows Forms Controls and Components with Rich Design-Time Features](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/a/7/3a7fa450-1f33-41f7-9e6d-3aa95b5a6aea/MSDNMagazineApril2003en-us.chm)
[May 2003 Building Windows Forms Controls and Components with Rich Design-Time Features, Part 2](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/a/7/3a7fa450-1f33-41f7-9e6d-3aa95b5a6aea/MSDNMagazineMay2003en-us.chm)

These are now .chm help files.  You will need to unblock in the file's property page to enable reading the contents after downloading.

Comment: The downside with not allowing an empty constructor is that you wont be able to use the control in design time.

Comment: The OP says it's a non-visual component he's creating, so this shouldn't be a problem.  The constructor I mean is the FooComponent constructor... I'll clarify that in the question

Comment: I see what you mean... if he literally means a `Component` he wants to drag and drop n the form, then you're right, he has to have a default constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do need the default constructor in order to drop the component on the form.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I will go over the article.

Comment: At first glance on the article I think it will get me started, I should have read it before asking my question :). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to define exactly what a contained class can be contained within. I've certainly never seen an instance where I've gotten an error (or even a warning) for setting up a property of one type in another, even in WinForms.

Something you might be able to do is to define a Form-derived ancestor for your forms that contains a reference to your (internally-visible) FooComponent, initializes one on instantiation, and attaches the handlers. For best results it should be parameterless and the only constructor overload, so it forms the base for any constructor your consumers come up with. Then, just make it a house rule that forms derive from your ancestor class and not directly from Form (you might be able to use a code inspection tool like FxCop or similar to enforce this when code is committed to source control). Your users now get a FooComponent in every Form they create, cannot create their own (it's internal and should be in another project with your Form ancestor) and don't have to do anything other than derive from the new class to make their forms behave the way you want.

Comment: I need this to be supported in design time, do you know of anyway to achieve #3 in design time?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for a lot.  In general, making components aware of the form they are dropped on is quite difficult.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018263/how-to-invoke-on-the-ui-thread-of-a-winform-component/4018436#4018436) can help you get the event handler implemented.  You'll need to implement ISupportInitialize to get the EndInit() call to setup the event handler.

Preventing multiples is quite hard too, I can only think of a custom designer that can step in early enough to prevent the 2nd one from being added.