# Determining when the Owner of a Component has Loaded

Tags: c#, winforms, components

I've created a WinForms application that includes a custom component.

The component needs to fire one of it's events on start up but, at the time the component's constructor is called, all of the event handlers are still null.

What I need is an event that tells me the window owning the component has loaded and all the event handlers have been set.

However, it appears that components have no `Load` event. In fact, it appears they don't come with any events at all with the sole exception of the `Disposed` event.

How can my component know when it's safe to fire off an event on start up?

Comment: It is really unclear how *any* code got to run in your component that could fire events.  That can only work if the code in the form class explicitly asks it to do something.  Or if you start a thread, in which case you've got bigger problems.  You ought to focus on the "when the form class explicit asks" angle, that's how all components work.  You can subscribe the form's Load event with [this trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4018436/17034).

Comment: This component manages all the file commands. When starting the app, the New command is implicitly executed. If the component could fire the events that indicate the file has changed, the form can have a single handler to handle every case where the file has changed (including when the app just started). In addition, it appears if I initialize the components public properties in my constructor, they are null by the time the form has loaded. The constructor is just too early to perform this initialization. This seems like a considerable oversight to me.

Comment: You haven't really addressed the greater question, *how does your component know a file has changed*?  How does that code run?  If you use FileSystemWatcher then you get an event on a worker thread, the bigger problem.  You'll need to post a snippet, this is too fuzzy.

Comment: My component adds handlers to the form's File commands. The open command, for example, saves the current file if it's modified, then displays an open file dialog where the user can select a file to open.  If a file is selected, it fires it's FileOpen event (where the form can do the actual reading of the file). If no error is signaled, the component knows the file has changed and fires it's FileChanged event. The component manages all this, tracking if the current file is modified, etc. So it knows when the file has changed.

Comment: How could the user possibly give the File+Open command when the form isn't ready?

Comment: You asked me how the component knows the file has changed and I answered, providing an example with the File Open command. As described above, the initialization I'd like to do on start up includes firing the FileNew event, firing the FileChanged (for our purposes, there is always a new file on start up, and the file has always changed after a new file), and initializing some public properties after the system apparently initializes them to null.

Comment: This all makes little sense to me.  Anyhoo, I gave you a link to a way to hook the form Load event.  Implementing the ISupportInitialize interface is another way to do it, the EndInit() method is called after the event handlers are subscribed.

Comment: @JonathanWood did you solve this issue? (I tried overriding Site but is called only during design time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution, is to fire the event when the Component is wired to the listener.  You need to create your own event property.

```
class MyClass
{
    private static readonly _myEvent = new object();

    private EventHandlerList _handlers = new EventHandlerList();

    public event EventHandler MyEvent
    {
        add 
        { 
            _handlers.AddHandler(_myEvent, value); 
           OnMyEvent(); // fire the startup event
        }
        remove { _handlers.RemoveHandler(_myEvent, value); }
    }

    private void OnMyEvent()
    {
        EventHandler myEvent = _handlers[_myEvent] as EventHandler;
        if (myEvent != null) myEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: How would the component know when this happens?

Comment: See the add part of the event property.

Comment: Thanks. This seems really unfortunately though. I have a number of events and initialization that needs to be performed, and the user might never add a handler. I could work through it but it will become quite complex. To me, this seems to be a missing part of the component design.

Comment: @JonathanWood what is the definition of a `loaded component`? when the declaration of the component is done? When some initialization of the component is done? or any thing else?

Comment: @KingKing: Well, my short answer is that the window that owns the component has been loaded. My longer answer is that the component has been fully initialized in relationship to the window that owns it. For example, if you declare handlers for the component events in the form designer, then things aren't fully initialized until after the point where those handlers have actually been set.

Comment: @JonathanWood I think you may have to define the fixed number of event handlers for your component and count the event handlers added until it reaches the fixed number and raise some your own event to notify that.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 different ways.
The first way is to keeping track of the container during design time using Site (Site is not called during runtime). It works just saving ContainerControl property during design time so during runtime it can be used.
You can see it in property browser of some components of the framework.

```
    private ContainerControl _containerControl;

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public ContainerControl ContainerControl
    {
        get { return _containerControl; }
        set
        {
            _containerControl = value;
            if (DesignMode || _containerControl == null)
                return;

            if (_containerControl is Form)
                ((Form) _containerControl).Load += (sender, args) => { Load(); };
            else if (_containerControl is UserControl)
                ((UserControl)_containerControl).Load += (sender, args) => { Load(); };
            else
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unknown container type. Cannot setup initialization.");
        }
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public override ISite Site
    {
        get { return base.Site; }
        set
        {
            base.Site = value;
            if (value == null)
                return;

            IDesignerHost host = value.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost)) as IDesignerHost;
            if (host == null)
                return;

            IComponent componentHost = host.RootComponent;

            if (componentHost is ContainerControl)
                ContainerControl = componentHost as ContainerControl;
        }
    }

    private void Load()
    {

    }
```

The second method is to implement ISupportInitialize in the Component.
In this case Visual Studio (2013) during design time generate the code that calls ISupportInitialize methods (BeginInit and EndInit) on the Component.